# Relationship between composite keyed table & non primary key table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables named ORDER_HEAD and ORDER_DETAIL, following is their structure.

**ORDER_HEAD**:

```
ORD_ID (PK)
ORD_TYPE (PK)
ORD_DATE
ORD_NET_TOTAL
```

**ORDER_DETAIL**:

```
ODD_ID
ODD_LINE_NO
ODD_PRODUCT_ID
ODD_QTY
```

I want to form a relationship between the `ORD_ID` in `ORDER_HEAD` & `ODD_ID` in `ORDER_DETAIL` table. But SQL Server shows an error message:

> primary key or unique constraint must be defined for table before it can participate in a relationship

Why am I getting this error ? Is there a way to perform a join between these two columns or is there a problem in my db design ?

Comment: If you have a **composite** PK made up from multiple columns, all foreign keys references **MUST** include **ALL** columns of the PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a relationship from `Composite primary key` then any reference should also include all the column's in `Composite primary key`

`Schema` of `ORDER_DETAIL` should be

```
ORDER_DETAIL
============
ODD_ID (Fk)
ORD_TYPE(Fk) -- you need to add this column
ODD_LINE_NO
ODD_PRODUCT_ID
ODD_QTY
```

Create `Foreign key` like this.

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_DETAIL
  FOREIGN KEY(ODD_ID, ORD_TYPE) REFERENCES ORDER_HEAD(ODD_ID, ORD_TYPE)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. isn't that going to duplicate the same data available in the ORDER_HEAD table. Both these columns will then contain the same value which is unnecessary.

Comment: @codeGEN - yeah same data will be present in both the tables but this the only way to create a foreign key out of composite primary key

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

After rethinking the problem I think you should achieve your goal by adding reference column `ODD_TYPE` (like user @NoDisplayName stated) and creating composite PK for your table `ORDER_DETAIL` consisting of 3 columns `(ODD_ID, ODD_TYPE,  ODD_LINE_NO)`, then it would be:

```
ORDER_DETAIL
============
ODD_ID          (PK)
ODD_TYPE        (PK)
ODD_LINE_NO     (PK)
ODD_PRODUCT_ID
ODD_QTY
```

in SQL it could be:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDER_DETAIL ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Order_Detail PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ODD_ID, ODD_TYPE, ODD_LINE_NO)
```

Then, in `ORDER_DETAIL` table for specific pair (`ODD_ID`, `ODD_TYPE`) you would have records being its order lines.

I think that after removing the previous PK, adding the column and setting the above key (even in visual editor) you shouldn't have problems when creating FK between the two tables and mapping the proper columns together.

Comment: I can't because one `ORDER_HEAD` can contain more than one `ORDER_DETAIL`.

Comment: I added the primary key as you have specified in your answer. But when I try to establish the relationship it shows the following error message. The columns in table 'ORDER_HEAD' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Could you write the exact code by which you are estabilishing the relationship which produces error?

Comment: I am using the designer in MSSQL (database diagram) to create the relationship. Not a written SQL statement.

Comment: Please find my updated answer. I hope it will be OK now. Regards.